# How to get the sum of elements pairs from list

Tags: python

I have list `lst = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

- if i m searching for 12, My out put should (4,8), (5,7)
- My current out is showing only (4,8)
- if i m printing my return then reverse of list is also printing like (4,8), (5,7),
  (8,4), (7,5)

```
def find_sum(s, lst):
    indices = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(lst)}
#     print(indices)
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        target = s - x
        if target in indices:
            return (lst[i], lst[indices[target]])

    return None

lst = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(find_sum(12, lst))
```

Expected `(4,8), (5,7)`

Comment: what's your actual?

Comment: you return immediately: `return (lst[i], lst[indices[target]])`... why do you *expect* to return `(4,8), (5,7)`???

Comment: We can add the tuple to the list, then check if the list is not empty,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already got several other answers, but just for fun, using recursion:

```py
def find_sum(s, lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1: # with list of length <= 1, impossible to find a pair
        return []
    x, sublst = lst[0], lst[1:]
    if s - x in sublst:
        return [(x, s - x)] + find_sum(s, sublst)
    else:
        return find_sum(s, sublst)

lst = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(find_sum(12, lst)) # [(4, 8), (5, 7)]
```

In each recursion step, given a list, we pick the head element (name it `x`) and the rest of the list `sublst`. If there is an element in `sublst` that sums with `x` to make the given number, then return `x` *and something else*. This something else part is where recursion happens; we have only considered pairs with `(x, y)` where `y` is in `sublst`, not pairs *within* the `sublst`. So we need to call `find_sum` again, with this `sublst`. This recursion process ends when the given list has length 1 or empty; in those cases there is no pairs to consider, so just return an empty list.

Note that `else` here is redundant, because of `return` before it. But I like it to be there anyway.

---

The following is another version using generator:

```py
def find_sum(s, lst):
    lst = lst.copy()
    while lst:
        x = lst.pop(0)
        if s - x in lst:
            yield x, s - x

lst = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(list(find_sum(12, lst))) # [(4, 8), (5, 7)]
```

Comment: @PaulRooney Thank you for the suggestion! I tried implementing a generator and added it. Since I am new to this concept, please let me know if it can be improved!

Comment: i m new to recursion, when and where it stops execution. where the iteration is happening.? . Can you explain the code

Comment: how you become expert in python, like dynamic programming

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import itertools

def find_sum(s, lst):
    return [x for x in itertools.combinations(lst, r=2) if x[0] + x[1] == s]

lst = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(find_sum(12, lst))
```

**Output**:

```
[(4, 8), (5, 7)]
```

Comment: Note that this is O(n!).

Comment: @enzo Isn't it *O(n^2)*?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, you're right, I misread it as permutations. Either way, the OP's solution is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

When you call `return`, you are ending the function. This means that once you find the first pair, your function ends, and you can't find anymore pairs.

To fix this, you should add an array in the function called `good_pairs` (or whatever you want). Instead of writing `return (lst[i], lst[indices[target]])`, you should write `good_pairs.append((lst[i], lst[indices[target]]))`.

At the end, simply return the `good_pairs` list.

Then just print it in whatever format you want.

Final Code:

```
def find_sum(s, lst):
    s.sort()
    good_pairs = []
    indices = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(lst[:len(lst)//2])}
    # print(indices)
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        target = s - x
        if target in indices:
            good_pairs.append((lst[i], lst[indices[target]]))

    return good_pairs

lst = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(find_sum(12, lst))
```

I first sorted the array, and then enumerated only half of the array to prevent duplicates. Credit to @enzo

Hope this helps and good luck :)

Comment: Nice answer! Just some missing details: 1) you forgot to create the `good_pairs` list inside the function and 2) the expected output for OP is (4,8), (5,7) instead of (4, 8), (5, 7), (6, 6), (7, 5), (8, 4), but you can fix this by replacing `enumerate(lst)` with `enumerate(lst[:len(lst)//2])` to search only the first half of the original list. Otherwise, this is the best answer I've ever experienced in StackOverflow.

Comment: List, not array

Comment: @enzo Thanks so much! I really appreciated the feedback. I'll make sure to fix up my code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Darn, I always mix those two terms up. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: good_pairs.append(lst[i], lst[indices[target]]) , it will throw error TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: @Nons Add a pair of parentheses on the edges to append a pair / tuple, not two separate elements. Sorry about that.

Comment: lst = [2, 4, 6, 7, 8,3,9,510], print(find_sum(14, lst)), expected is `[(8, 6), (9, 5), (10, 4)]`. but in your case its `[(7, 7), (8, 6), (10, 4)]`

Comment: i think sorting is mandatory in your case

Comment: @Nons You are correct. My apologies as this is my first ever Stack Overflow answer. I'll try to not make careless errors in the future.

Comment: @Nons Just did. No problem!

Answer (score 1):

`return` ends the function. You can use `yield` instead, which is like a multi-return.

To avoid reversed duplicates, you can simply check that `x <= target`.

You also need to add `i != indices[target]` to make sure that you don't get `(6, 6)`.

```
def find_sum(s, lst):
    indices = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(lst)}
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        target = s - x
        if x <= target and target in indices and i != indices[target]:
            yield x, target  # <- I also simplified this
```

```
>>> lst = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list(find_sum(12, lst))  # <- Note the `list()` here.
[(4, 8), (5, 7)]
```

---

Although, thinking about it a bit more, `indices` doesn't account for multiple instances. If that's on purpose, then `lst` can be cast to `set` without losing any info, and the solution becomes a bit simpler:

```
def find_sum(s, lst):
    targets = set(lst)
    for x in targets:
        target = s - x
        if x < target and target in targets:
            yield x, target
```

Comment: If `lst = [2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]`, then `i != indices[target]` will cut off one of the variants

Comment: @АлексейР Yes, that's on purpose. I'm just about to edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Counting the the pairs with sum divisible by an integer k

```
def divisibleSumPairs(n, k, ar):
   
    import itertools
    
    return len([x for x in itertools.combinations(ar,r=2) if (x[0]+x[1])%k==0])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).